# Wild automorphisms of a free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $F_X$ be a free group on a countably infinite set $X$. Let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $F_X$ and $H$ a closed subgroup of $F_X$ in the profinite topology.

> Is it possible that $\alpha(H) \lneq H$?

Note that if $\alpha$ is the conjugation by some $r \in F_X$ then the answer is negative.

Comment: Isn't every finitely generated subgroup of a free group closed in the profinite topology? If so, just take $H=\langle x\rangle$ and make $\alpha$ exchange $x$ with some other free generator...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am asking whether $\alpha$ can map $H$ to a proper subgroup of itself.

Comment: Oh; misinterpreted that. Sorry.

Comment: Choose $X=\mathbf{Z}$, and $\alpha$ be the shift on generators $x_n\mapsto x_{n+1}$, and $H=F_\mathbf{N}$. Clearly $\alpha(H)$ is properly contained in $H$. Also $H$ is closed in the profinite topology, by a simple argument.

Comment: @YCor you are right!