# Wild automorphisms of profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

> Is there a profinite group $G$, a continuous automorphism $\alpha$ of
>   $G$ and a topologically finitely generated closed subgroup $H \leq G$
>   such that $\alpha(H) \lneq H$ ?

Note that if an example exists, then $G$ is not topologically finite generated, and $\alpha$ is not given by conjugation by an element of $G$.

If we allow $H$ not to be topologically finitely generated, then the example given by Yves de-Cornullier in [Wild automorphisms of a free group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224360/wild-automorphisms-of-a-free-group) gives rise to an example here.

Comment: Since I answered the other question in a comment (because it was really a trivial example), I would rather suggest you edit that other question and erase this one.

Comment: @YCor maybe this is a good idea but I do not know how to erase a question.

Comment: An artefact would be to first edit the other one, then to edit this one as "Now a duplicate of... " and the question will be quickly closed as duplicate (and even erased by a moderator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Let $K_n = K_n(G)$ be the intersection of all open normal subgroups of $G$ of index at most $n$.  Then $\alpha(K_n) = K_n$.  If we replace $G$ with $G/K_n$, we still have $\alpha$ acting as an automorphism on $G/K_n$ and for $n$ large enough, $\alpha(H)K_n/K_n$ is a proper subgroup of $HK_n/K_n$ (since $H$ and $\alpha(H)$ are both closed, we can distinguish them using finite images of $G$).  So we may assume $K_n(G)$ is trivial for some $n$.  It then follows that $K_n(H)$ is trivial.  But if a topologically finitely generated profinite group $H$ satisfies $K_n(H) = 1$ for some $n$, then $H$ must be finite, since $H$ only has finitely many finite quotients of any given order.  This gives a contradiction.